# Firebase extension sudden deployment validation error

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

Today when making some changes to my frontend and tried to deploy i suddenly get this error regarding an extension

```
Extensions deploy had errors:

- configure moralis-auth
you have not accepted the Firebase Extensions User Terms of Service for project ctseer-b6274; to accept the terms, install an extension via the Firebase console or via the Firebase CLI in an interactive shell


Error: Extensions deployment failed validation. No changes have been made to the Extension instances on ctseer-b6274
```

I've changed nothing regarding the extension (even says so in the error??) yet it stopped being able to deploy. The extension still works fine and had no changes recently. it's rough to simply uninstall / install quickly so was wondering what the problem could be here?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Tried reinstalling. Exact same issue, after installation and trying to deploy it, fails on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This morning looks like it got fixed in a newer version. Contacted firebase team and they were working it. If you run into this issue, run `npm install -g firebase-tools` and redeploy